# Changing computer name didn't change my full username on Windows 7 Home Premium

Tags: windows, windows-7

I had to change the computer name from SomePC to Prefix-SomePC. However Windows on Object Explorer have kept the SomePC\Username instead of Prefix-SomePC\UserName.

Any ideas how to fix that via command line? It is on a PC running Windows Home Premium so I can't access the Local Users and Groups.

Comment: This sounds more of a SuperUser question, as it sounds like you want to change your username, not your computer name, which are two entirely separate things. You need to change your account information to change the username (or create a new account and move information over to that profile). If other people agree with this it'll be voted to migrate automatically to SuperUser, you don't need to do anything to enable that migration.

Comment: Are you referring to Object Explorer in SQL Mgt Studio - using SQL Express perhaps?

Comment: Did you restart the PC?